# no tests run, please check the configuration settings

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm runnings VS code with Python. I get the above warning when I select run test in the edit window or run current unit test file. running debug seems to work ok. 
Why?
My workspace setting look like:

```
   {
        "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\declan\\python.exe",
        "python.unitTest.unittestArgs": [
            "-v",
            "-s",
            ".",
            "-p",
            "*Test*.py"
        ],
        "python.unitTest.pyTestEnabled": false,
        "python.unitTest.nosetestsEnabled": false,
        "python.unitTest.unittestEnabled": true
    }
```

I have not changed defaults otherwise.

Comment: Please share your configuration settings so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be several faults in the code and test code.